# How do I check two Typescript object arrays for equivalence when some objects have multiple equivalencies?

Tags: angular, typescript, algorithm, compare, equivalent

I am coding a cost function for a game. Players have a *hand* of `n < 14` Resources of the following possible types:

```
Fire, Air, Water, Earth, Good, Evil, Law, Chaos, Void
```

These are subdivided into two Categories: Elements (Fire, Air, Water, Earth) and Philosophies (Good, Evil, Law, Chaos). Actions taken by the player have a *cost*, which may be any combination of Resources or Categories.

- Example cost: `[Fire, Air, Evil, Philosophy, Philosophy]`

Each resource in the *cost* must be paid by the corresponding resource from the player's *hand*. Categories in the cost may be filled by any Resource in that Category. Costs may also include `Any`, which can be filled by any Resource type. To pay a cost, the player must *select* Resources from their *hand*, then click on the Action. This triggers an evaluation function which returns `True` if the *selected* Resources fulfill the *cost*.

`Void` is a "wildcard" Resource that may be used to pay for any other Resource. (This does not apply the other way around - a player cannot fulfill a `Void` cost by paying with another resource.)

- A valid payment for the example cost above would be `[Void, Void, Air, Good, Good]`

I am currently stumped for how to implement this. My current evaluation function cannot handle the substitutions of Categories or `Void`; it simply checks for exact equivalence:

```
  /** Returns true if the resources currently selected by the player
   * satisfy the @cost of the option selected */
  evaluatePayment(cost: Resource[]): boolean {
    let isValidPayment: boolean = true;
    if (cost) {
      const playerSelectedResources: Resource[] = this.playerHand
        .filter(r => r.isSelected)
        .map(hr => hr.type);
      // Check that selected resources cover cost
      const missingCost = cost.filter(r => playerSelectedResources.indexOf(r));
      // Check that no additional resources are selected
      const excessPaid = playerSelectedResources.filter(r => cost.indexOf(r));
      if (missingCost.length > 0 || excessPaid.length > 0) {
        isValidPayment = false;
      }
    }
    return isCostSelected;
  }
```

Based on feedback, here is a better formulation of the problem:

```
enum Resource {
  FIRE,
  AIR,
  WATER,
  EARTH,
  GOOD,
  EVIL,
  LAW,
  CHAOS,
  VOID,
  ELEMENT,    // This can only appear in a Cost, never a Payment
  PHILOSOPHY, // This can only appear in a Cost, never a Payment
  ANY         // This can only appear in a Cost, never a Payment
}

export const ElementResources: Resource[] = [Resource.FIRE, Resource.AIR, Resource.WATER, Resource.EARTH];
export const PhilosophyResources: Resource[] = [Resource.GOOD, Resource.EVIL, Resource.LAW, Resource.CHAOS];


function isValidExactPayment(cost: Resource[], payment: Resource[]): boolean {
  /** Logic here
   * Returns True if payment matches cost exactly, 
   * according to the rules above */
}
```

Some more examples:

```
/** Example 1 */
const cost: Resource[] = [Resource.WATER, Resource, EVIL];

isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.WATER, Resource.EVIL]); // true
isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.EVIL, Resource.VOID]); // true
isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.VOID, Resource.EVIL]); // true, order should not matter
isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.WATER, Resource.VOID]); // true


/** Example 2 */
const cost: Resource[] = [Resource.VOID];

isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.VOID]); // true
isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.EVIL]); // false


/** Example 3 */
const cost: Resource[] = [Resource.GOOD];

isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.GOOD]); // true
isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.VOID]); // true
isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.EVIL]); // false


/** Example 4 */
const cost: Resource[] = [Resource.AIR, Resource.PHILOSOPHY, Resource.PHILOSOPHY];

isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.AIR, Resource.EVIL, Resource.CHAOS]); // true
isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.VOID, Resource.GOOD, Resource.GOOD]); // true
isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.AIR, Resource.CHAOS, Resource.VOID]); // true


/** Example 5 */
const cost: Resource[] = [Resource.ELEMENT]

isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.FIRE]); // true
isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.AIR]); // true
isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.WATER]); // true
isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.EARTH]); // true
isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.VOID]); // true


/** Example 6 */
const cost: Resource[] = [Resource.WATER, Resource.ANY, Resource.ANY]

isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.WATER, Resource.WATER, Resource.WATER]); // true
isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.FIRE, Resource.FIRE, Resource.FIRE]); // false
isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.VOID, Resource.WATER, Resource.LAW]); // true

/** Example 7 */
const cost: Resource[] = [Resource.FIRE, Resource.EVIL, Resource.PHILOSOPHY, Resource.ELEMENT];

isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.FIRE, Resource.EVIL, Resource.EVIL, Resource.EARTH]); // true
isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.FIRE, Resource.EVIL, Resource.EVIL, Resource.VOID]); // true
isValidExactPayment(cost, [Resource.VOID, Resource.EVIL, Resource.GOOD, Resource.WATER]); // true
```

I'm currently pretty stumped for how to implement the more complex cost evaluation function.

Comment: What is `Philosophy` in `[Fire, Air, Evil, Philosophy, Philosophy]`?  Is there any way you could pare this down to a [mre] so that you just have a single function you need to implement instead of worrying about class methods and `isSelected()`?  I'd say you want an implementation of `function isValidPayment(cost: Resource[], payment: Resource[]): boolean`

Comment: I suspect there are some category enum values missing like `Resource.ELEMENT` and `Resource.PHILOSOPHY` but you haven't defined them, just mentioned them

Comment: Like [here](https://tsplay.dev/N5PVZw) is one way someone might do it, but I had to add the categories. Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing? It is probably helpful either way for you to write up some input/output examples (as I showed in the link above) so that people know what counts as a valid and an invalid payment.

Comment: @jcalz I tried to add as much useful information as I could. Previously missing notes:  `ANY` is a valid cost, and payment must be exact. Your write-up is almost certainly the correct approach, but `VOID` only acts as a wildcard when part of the payment, which invalidates a few of the examples.

Comment: Well, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w6PQ6m) work for your needs?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, this implementation works! I've been unable to break it with any valid test cases. Amazing work. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, I didn't see the part about payments being exact though, for that you'd just have to check if there's any leftover payments at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make things simpler you can reorganize the resources / costs. For example `ANY` is not a resource, it is only a cost. Here is one way to do it:

```js
enum Elements {
  FIRE = 'fire',
  AIR = 'air',
  WATER = 'water',
  EARTH = 'earth',
}

enum Philosophies {
  GOOD = 'good',
  EVIL = 'evil',
  LAW = 'law',
  CHAOS = 'chaos',
}

enum Void {
  VOID = 'void',
}

enum Resource {
  VOID = Void.VOID,
  FIRE = Elements.FIRE,
  AIR = Elements.AIR,
  WATER = Elements.WATER,
  EARTH = Elements.EARTH,
  GOOD = Philosophies.GOOD,
  EVIL = Philosophies.EVIL,
  LAW = Philosophies.LAW,
  CHAOS = Philosophies.CHAOS,
}

const ANY = 'any';
const ELEMENT = 'element';
const PHILOSOPHY = 'philosophy';
type Cost = Resource | typeof ANY | typeof ELEMENT | typeof PHILOSOPHY;
```

I like to use string constants rather than numeric enums, much better for debugging.

There are some other logical groups here, for instance a cost of `ELEMENT` can be paid for with `Elements` or `Void` so we can create some data structures for those. Also, turning the enums into an array will be helpful for iterating.

```js
const allResources = Object.values(Resource);

const elementsAndVoid: (Elements | Void)[] = [];
for (const e of Object.values(Elements)) elementsAndVoid.push(e);
elementsAndVoid.push(Void.VOID);

const philosophiesAndVoid: (Philosophies | Void)[] = [];
for (const p of Object.values(Philosophies)) philosophiesAndVoid.push(p);
philosophiesAndVoid.push(Void.VOID);
```

We need to know the amounts of each resource in both the cost and payment arrays before we can begin processing. It would be much easier to store the resources as key-value pairs rather than arrays (for example `{ fire: 2, water: 3 }`). Instead of refactoring your code I'll just convert the array to key-value pairs in the function, but definitely something you should consider.

If our costs and payments are all counted, we can pay for each cost by decrementing the cost by one, and decrementing whatever we pay with by one. This needs to be done in order of specificity. For example if we blow all our `FIRE` on `ELEMENT`, we might be short on `FIRE` when we try to pay for it, when we had plenty of `WATER` to pay for `ELEMENT`. So the more specific costs take precedence.

If we ever get a cost that is greater than 0, but nothing to pay with, then we know we can't cover the cost.

Here's an implementation:

```js
function isValidExactPayment(costs: Cost[], payments: Resource[]): boolean {
  // count payment amounts
  const paymentCounts: { [key: string]: number } = {};
  for (const p of payments) {
    if (paymentCounts[p] === undefined) paymentCounts[p] = 0;
    paymentCounts[p]++;
  }
  // count cost amounts
  const costCounts: { [key: string]: number } = {};
  for (const c of costs) {
    if (costCounts[c] === undefined) costCounts[c] = 0;
    costCounts[c]++;
  }
  // Attempt to pay for specific resource - void first
  for (const r of allResources) {
    while (costCounts[r] > 0) {
      if (paymentCounts[r] > 0) {
        costCounts[r]--;
        paymentCounts[r]--;
      }
      // Use leftover void if there's not enough
      else if (paymentCounts[Resource.VOID] > 0) {
        costCounts[r]--;
        paymentCounts[Resource.VOID]--;
      }
      // Not enough specific resource
      else {
        console.log('Not enough:', r);
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  // Attempt to pay for general elements
  for (const r of elementsAndVoid) {
    while (costCounts[ELEMENT] > 0 && paymentCounts[r] > 0) {
      costCounts[ELEMENT]--;
      paymentCounts[r]--;
    }
  }
  // Not enough elements
  if (costCounts[ELEMENT] > 0) {
    console.log('Not enough:', ELEMENT);
    return false;
  }
  // Attempt to pay for general philosophies
  for (const r of philosophiesAndVoid) {
    while (costCounts[PHILOSOPHY] > 0 && paymentCounts[r] > 0) {
      costCounts[PHILOSOPHY]--;
      paymentCounts[r]--;
    }
  }
  // Not enough philosophies
  if (costCounts[PHILOSOPHY] > 0) {
    console.log('Not enough:', PHILOSOPHY);
    return false;
  }
  // Attempt to pay for any with anything
  for (const r of allResources) {
    while (costCounts[ANY] > 0 && paymentCounts[r] > 0) {
      costCounts[ANY]--;
      paymentCounts[r]--;
    }
  }
  // Not enough any
  if (costCounts[ANY] > 0) {
    console.log('Not enough:', ANY);
    return false;
  }
  // Paid in full :)
  console.log('Paid in full');
  return true;
}
```

There's obviously performance optimizations that can be done, but this works.